# Alarm From MySQL Data in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Hi I am a total noob at PHP and was trying to figure out where to start. I am looking into PHP setting an alarm from high temp reading from MySQL so I can add an alarm to Joomla index page on high temp readings and show the database name and what probe was at a high.

Here is a pic of the database - thanks for having a look for me.

The database is set out like this:

```
datetime             temp1  temp2   temp3   temp4   temp5   temp6   temp7   temp8   
2011-12-11 17:21:09  45     44      55      55      36      44      35      78
```

Comment: I'm sorry, could you try explaining what you want again?  I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: It looks like you might want to have three fields instead - `datetime`, `reading`, `sensor` - then you can write better SQL. Example: 2011-12-11 17:21:09, 45, 1 || 2011-12-11 17:21:09, 44, 2 etc... The basic idea is you have one row per reading

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to use php to read the database and anytime that it finds a very high reading, it will update something so that your webpage will display an alarm? I assume that you already have something that inserts these temp values in the database.

So going on..

you just need to create a **[cron job](http://www.developertutorials.com/tutorials/php/running-php-cron-jobs-regular-scheduled-tasks-in-php-172/)** with your php file, have it run say once every ten minutes, or however frequent you want. The cron job will basically look up in the database where-ever the temp is beyond what you want. When it does, you can update another field in a different table that your joomla page reads off. This field ideally should just be an id indicating which sensor and whatnot. So I agree with the comments that you should rethink how to structure your tables.

Comment: Almost seems like a better idea to test the values as they come into the DB instead of a chron...

Comment: @then there would really be no need to keep track of all those temperature readings like he is doing. Depends on his setup I guess.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few database reading options, the best of which seems to be [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). After you understand how to get the database info into php, it should be trivial to set a couple `if` statements to check the temperatures. You may also find it beneficial to read a simple [PHP tutorial](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php) or two. Once you have that under your belt, ask about adding this 'alarm' to Joomla again.

EDIT: a quick google reveals [Joomla's PHP Essentials](http://docs.joomla.org/PHP_essentials).